# How can I export just the file names of commits to a txt file in git?

Tags: git

I'm trying to export the file names of the files that were changed through commits in git to a txt file. How can I approach this problem? I just want the file name and I would like one file name on each line instead of all of them clumped together. Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+files+commit

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** shorter / simpler version (no need for `log -1` here when you have `show`)

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only <commitHash> > file.txt
```

---

**Original answer**

```
git log --name-only <commitHash> -1 --pretty=format:'' > file.txt
```

will list the related files for any given commit, and print the list, one file per line, in `file.txt`. ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---name-only))

Note that you could also filter the type of operation relevant for the listing here. I mean, you could list only *modified* files, or *deleted* files, for example.

Comment: Some constructive criticism for the downvote? I don't mind the rep, just want to improve on a mistake if any :-)

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for correction by RomainValeri. My command just made a little modification, it shows file names by date order:

```
git log -1 --date-order  --name-only  --pretty=format:'' > myAllCommittedFiles.txt
```

Comment: Did you actually *try* any of these commands in a terminal? OP wants a list of the files, one per line, without extra info. I'm pretty sure that you're outputting way too much things here...

Comment: git log --date-order  --pretty=oneline --name-only > myAllCommittedFiles.txt this does what's the issue?

Comment: No, this outputs commit hashes also. try it in any repo, you'll see for yourself.

Comment: No it only shows file name to me

Comment: Hmm... that's odd. Let's check versions, it must be something they changed in the output format at some point. `git version 2.21.0.windows.1` for me. You?

Comment: Ok you win. Happy?

Comment: I'm not "winning" anything. Here I've been on your team all along. And Brian too. We're all together against ignorance.